# Highlight active window on MobaXterm Split pane

Tags: mobaxterm

In iTerm2, on the split pane, active window gets a black background once chosen meaning it is now an active window. The other windows on the same pane gets grayed out. Is this something possible in MobaXterm? I'm using free version of MobaXterm.

Thanks